# Need solution for sql-ex.ru/ DML ex4

Tags: sql

I'm stuck in the 4th DML problem from sql-ex

```
For each group of laptops with the identical model number, add following record into PC table:
code: minimal code among laptops in the group +20;
model: laptop's model number +1000;
speed: maximal speed among laptops in the group;
ram: maximal ram size among laptops in the group *2
hd: maximal hd capacity among laptops in the group *2;
cd: default value;
price: maximal price among laptops in the group divided by 1.5.
Remark. Consider model number as numeric.
```

The schema is

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: try looking up insert into with select for inserting data from other tables and group by with aggregates (MIN, MAX) to get the data u need to insert (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/insert-select.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13sql-1886636.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
insert into PC (code,model,speed,ram,hd,price) 
select min(code)+20,model+1000,max(speed),max(ram)*2,max(hd)*2,max(price)/1.5 
from Laptop group by model
```